# Swipe for Recycle View doesn't work properly

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I would like to implement swipe for my recycle view as a whole(not to the individual item row).
I have tried using swipe gesture ,on touch listener custom class but still  it didn't not work smoothly.
at times it works ok but most of the time it get swipes left to right only even if I swipe right to left. 
below is my custom class code . and I have implemented it for the recycle view in my fragment class. 
sorry that I can't post my entire code as i was not suppose to do it. can any one help me out please.  ?

````
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
public class RelativeLayoutTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
    static final String logTag = "ActivitySwipeDetector";
    public Context activity;
    static final int MIN_DISTANCE = 100;// TODO change this runtime based on screen resolution. for 1920x1080 is to small the 100 distance
    private float downX, downY, upX, upY;
    MaterialCalendarView calendarView;
    String slectedDate;
    Calendar calendar;
    ICalendarEventList list_interf_obcj;
    // ISwipeFragment iSwipeFragment;

    public RelativeLayoutTouchListener(Context mainActivity, MaterialCalendarView calendarViewes, String slectedDatesnew, Calendar calendares, ICalendarEventList list_interf_obcj, ISwipeFragment iSwipeFragment) {
        this.activity = mainActivity;
        this.slectedDate = slectedDatesnew;
        this.calendarView = calendarViewes;
        this.calendar = calendares;
        this.list_interf_obcj = list_interf_obcj;
        //this.iSwipeFragment = iSwipeFragment;
    }

    public void setDate(String slectedDatesnew) {
        this.slectedDate = slectedDatesnew;
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                downX = event.getX();
                downY = event.getY();
                return true;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                upX = event.getX();
                upY = event.getY();

                float deltaX = downX - upX;
                float deltaY = downY - upY;

                // swipe horizontal?
                if (Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE) {
                    // left or right
                    if (deltaX < 0) {
                        //   v.scrollBy(5,5);
                        // setDate(NewCalendarFragment.selectedDate);

                        onLeftToRightSwipe();
                        return true;
                    }
                    if (deltaX > 0) {
                        //   v.scrollBy(5,5);
                        //  setDate(NewCalendarFragment.selectedDate);
                        onRightToLeftSwipe();
                        return true;
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.i(logTag, "Swipe was only " + Math.abs(deltaX) + " long horizontally, need at least " + MIN_DISTANCE);
                    // return false; // We don't consume the event
                }

                // swipe vertical?
                if (Math.abs(deltaY) > MIN_DISTANCE) {
                    // top or down
                    if (deltaY < 0) {
                        this.onTopToBottomSwipe();
                        return true;
                    }
                    if (deltaY > 0) {
                        this.onBottomToTopSwipe();
                        return true;
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.i(logTag, "Swipe was only " + Math.abs(deltaX) + " long vertically, need at least " + MIN_DISTANCE);
                    // return false; // We don't consume the event
                }

                return false; // no swipe horizontally and no swipe vertically
            }// case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void onRightToLeftSwipe() {
        Log.i(logTag, "RightToLeftSwipe!");
        leftToRightAction(calendar, calendarView, activity, list_interf_obcj, slectedDate);
    }


    public void onLeftToRightSwipe() {
        Log.i(logTag, "LeftToRightSwipe!");
        rightToLeftAction(calendar, calendarView, activity, list_interf_obcj, slectedDate);
    }

    public void onTopToBottomSwipe() {
        Log.i(logTag, "onTopToBottomSwipe!");
    }

    public void onBottomToTopSwipe() {
        Log.i(logTag, "onBottomToTopSwipe!");
    }


    private void rightToLeftAction(Calendar calendarold, MaterialCalendarView calendarView, Context mainActivity, ICalendarEventList list_interf_obcj, String selectedDates) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat parser = null;
        try {
            parser = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.US);
            calendar.setTime(parser.parse(selectedDates));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
           Log.i(logTag, "RightSwipe!--> " + calendar.getTime().toString());
        calendarView.setDateSelected(calendar.getTime(), true);
        calendarView.setSelectedDate(calendar.getTime());
        Log.i(logTag, "RightSwipe!--> " + calendar.getTime().toString());
        SimpleDateFormat formated = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        String onDateSelected_format = formated.format(calendar.getTime()).toString();
        setDate(parser.format(calendar.getTime()));
        calendarView.setFocusable(true);
        calendarView.setCurrentDate(calendar);

        new CalendarEventListTask(mainActivity, JsonUtil.CalendarListAPiJsonFormat(mainActivity, SessionStores.getSchoolId(mainActivity).toString(), onDateSelected_format, ""), Constants.CAl_LIST_TAG, list_interf_obcj, onDateSelected_format);

    }

    private void leftToRightAction(Calendar calendarold, MaterialCalendarView calendarView, Context mainActivity, ICalendarEventList list_interf_obcj, String selectedDates) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
           SimpleDateFormat parser = null;
        try {
            parser = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.US);

            calendar.setTime(parser.parse(selectedDates));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);

        Log.i(logTag, "LeftSwipe!--> " + calendar.getTime().toString());

        calendarView.setDateSelected(calendar.getTime(), true);

        calendarView.setSelectedDate(calendar.getTime());
        SimpleDateFormat formated = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        String onDateSelected_format = formated.format(calendar.getTime()).toString();
        setDate(parser.format(calendar.getTime()));
               calendarView.setFocusable(true);
        calendarView.setCurrentDate(calendar);


        new CalendarEventListTask(mainActivity, JsonUtil.CalendarListAPiJsonFormat(mainActivity, SessionStores.getSchoolId(mainActivity).toString(), onDateSelected_format, ""), Constants.CAl_LIST_TAG, list_interf_obcj, onDateSelected_format);     

    }

}```
````

Comment: you want to swipe many items at a single time ?

Comment: not really . the entire recycle view i want to swipe

Answer (score 0):

first of all , you can use the new Navigation gesture , check this link :

https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/gesturenav

in the other hand , why dont you put your recyclerView inside a viewPager , it will handle the swipe and your view will swipe in a good shape

you can put the recyclerView inside a view or inside a fragment and you can use this workflow to do what you want

Comment: i tired already with the view pager but the scroll up and down and on touch of the recycle view is not working properly again. and FYI this recycle view is inside a fragment already .

Comment: try to put the Recycler in a nestedScroll view and check